# next-images Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, next-images

I'm trying to load an image with next-images:
when i type in the image name it works fine:

```
//Working
<Image src={require(`../../images/exampleImage.jpg` )}/>
```

but i dont want that i want dynamic url like this:

```
//Not working
<img src={require(`../../images/${image}.jpg` )}/>
```

i get this error:

---

### Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

my next.config.js file:

```
const withImages = require("next-images");
module.exports = withImages();
```

i also tried this config:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
      }
    )
    return config
  },
}
```

I tried many methods but none seems to work please help, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to have a dynamic import path. Depending on the amount of images, I'd just import them all normally. If there's a large amount then maybe it's better to not import at all and and serve them as static files, this way you could construct dynamic paths.

Comment: @EyalC i can't do that because i'm implementing a image upload functionality in my website user can upload images and i store them on ./images so i need to have a dynamic import path

Comment: Are you storing the uploaded images under the `public` folder of your app? Files added at runtime to the `public` folder won't be available; only assets that are there at build time will be served by Next.js. Try using a third-party service to store your images instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using the `file-loader` library to handle images on the project. You could install the library and set the rules like this on webpack:

```
...
config.module.rules.push(
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    use: {
      loader: "file-loader"
    },
  }
),
```

You can read more about file-loader from its documentation on [webpack](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

Comment: i get this error: Error: Cannot find module './c7844f96-7cb7-43cf-ac34-d407fd32ce3eb.jpg'
that long filename is ${image}

Comment: great, you can remove the options for now. I would update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: okay now i don't get the error but the images are not loading

Comment: the images have this path: http://localhost:3000/44044f6c6e6b4f631ff968d1a2ed9264.jpg which is invalid path

Comment: I just read your question again now, and it occurred to me that you're trying to load an image dynamically.  Is the complete image coming from the backend? Do you already have the image as an asset on the Client side? or it's only the name of the image that is coming from backend?

Comment: i'm storing images on ./images folder

Comment: If you don't mind, why do you want to dynamically load the "name" of the image? Perhaps, I might be able to suggest another approach?

Comment: i'm implementing a image upload functionality in my website user can upload images and i store them on ./images so i need to have a dynamic import path and name of the image...

Comment: I would suggest you have a backend service and a cloud bucket like s3 to handle something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is most likely trying to find & include your images at the build time. This cannot work with reading the name from a variable. You have 2 options:

- manage images differently
- if you have a finite (or rather short) list of images, just import all & use some kind of switch to control which image is displayed.

Comment: 'manage images differently' what do you mean by   that?

Comment: sorry for confusing wording, I meant what was already mentioned in the comments:
> Try using a third-party service to store your images instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

- delete all your code in the `next.config.js`
- add the below codes instead:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = { 
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
        dangerouslyAllowSVG: true,
        contentSecurityPolicy: "default-src 'self'; script-src 'none'; sandbox;",
    },
};
    
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

It resolved my problem.